# How to get a Git repo url saved in a bash script to a variable

Tags: node.js, git, bash, github

In my bash script that runs postinstall to npm install I want to get the Github remote url for a specific repo named base.  But, when this runs the value extracted is "git" and not the URL to my git repository.  How would you capture the returned URL from this command?

```
#!/bin/bash
...
remoteBackup=git config --get remote.base.url
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var=$(command that produces output)` not `var=value command`.

The latter runs `command` with `var` in the environment set to `value`.

Assuming that's what you actually have in your script and not a typo. If it is a typo and that gets you back `git` and not `git@bitbucket` then it sounds like your config is messed up.

Comment: Hi, thanks that works great I didn't know you had to wrap a command like that to get it assigned.  Sorry, I'll fix the question and just put my git repository URL.